# Difeomorphism between two smooth manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I want to prove that $M:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}^3:\|x\|=\|y\|=1, \langle x,y\rangle=0\}$ is diffeomorphic to $\text{SO}(3,\mathbb{R})$.

By now, I have proven via the regular value theorem that $M$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}^3$, considering the morphism $\zeta:\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ given by 
$$\zeta(x,y)=\left(\|x\|-1,\|y\|-1,\langle x,y\rangle\right)$$
where $M=\zeta^{-1}(0,0,0)$. How should I proceed now?

Comment: I'm not really clear on what your saying. You want to prove $M$ is diffeomorphic to $SO(3)$? If I understand your definition of $M$ I don't see how these are diffeomorphic, the dimension is off. Remember $SO(3)$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{RP}^n$.

Comment: @Wintermute But $\text{SO}(3)$ has dimension 3 just like $M$, I don't see any problem with the dimension. This can be seen via $F:\mathcal{M}(3,\mathbb{R})\rightarrow\text{S}(3,\mathbb{R})\simeq\mathbb{R}^6$ defined as $F(A)=A^TA$

Comment: The proof is quite simple you already have two columns of an orthogonal matrix. Note, you get the third column vector by $z=x\times y$.